# Echo Mongo Data into categories with single database hit in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to print data from a mongodb into categories based on a particular field with a single cursor.  I am not extremely adept with php so I'm having trouble executing it.

Here is the code that I got:

```
$mongo = new MongoClient();
          $cursor1 = $mongo->phone->users_new->find(array('step'=>'current'));
          $cursor1->sort(array('date_created'=>-1));
          $cursor2 = $mongo->phone->users_new->find(array('step'=>'web'));
          $cursor2->sort(array('date_created'=>-1));
          foreach($cursor1 as $a){
              foreach($a as $b=>$c){
                  $value = $c;
                  if($b == 'date_created'){
                      $value =  date('m/d/Y', $c->sec); 
                  }
                  $record[$b] = $value;
              }
              $result['records']['current'][]= $record;
          }
          foreach($cursor2 as $a){
              foreach($a as $b=>$c){
                  $value = $c;
                  if($b == 'date_created'){
                      $value =  date('m/d/Y', $c->sec); 
                  }
                  $record[$b] = $value;
              }
              $result['records']['web'][]= $record;
          }
          header("Content-Type: application/json");
          echo '<pre>'.json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Essentially I want the data to print out like this:

```
{
"records": {
    "web": [
        {
            "name": "bob",
            "age": 32
        }
    ],
    "current": [
        {
            "name": "jones",
            "age": 72
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear from your code how you expect to get to the end output, and mostly because we have no idea what your documents look like or how your current logic is working to produce this. But I can help you with the single cursor part and general logic.

All you really need here is an [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition, or better yet an [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator, which is shorter syntax. Simply select both of your queried values for "step" and then discern between which array you are adding to in your code:

```
# Single query and better syntax
$cursor = $mongo->phone->users_new->find(array( 
   'step' => array( '$in' => array( 'current', 'web' ) )
))->sort(array( 'date_created' => -1))

# Basically copying your block of code
foreach ( cursor as $a ) {
    foreach( $a as $b=>$c){
        $value = $c;
        if ( $b == 'date_created' ) {
            $value =  date('m/d/Y', $c->sec); 
        }
        $record[$b] = $value;
    }

    # But decide on the array based on content. If not 'current' it's 'web'
    if ( $a["step"] == 'current' ) {
        $result['records']['current'][]= $record;
    } else {
        $result['records']['web'][]= $record;
    }
}

# The rest of your code
```

So basically "step" is the field you are selecting on and it will be present in the results. Just ask for "both" terms to be returned with a single query and then logically determine which array to add to.

Hopefully some of those added lines might give you some pointers on how to more efficiently code the rest of what you need to do here as well.